# SELECT last date from multiples values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table:

[image]

I want to make a query that allows me to show the **last** value in `fecha_gestion`
grouped by `NitSec`. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT id_log, fecha_gestion, nitsec 
FROM table 
GROUP BY nitsec 
ORDER BY fecha_gestion DESC
```

The result I want is this:

```
ID_log | fecha_gestion    | nitsec  
6      | 2020-01-03 09:52 | 5443
11     | 2020-01-03 10:12 | 1 
15     | 2020-01-03 10:23 | 3286
```

After doing this I need an inner join (but I can do it easily). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to number rows appropriately using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id_log, fecha_gestion, nitsec
FROM (
   SELECT 
      id_log, fecha_gestion, nitsec,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nitsec ORDER BY fecha_gestion DESC) AS rn
   FROM table 
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the perfect match

Answer (score 1):

Because no sample data was given, the next query is untested:

```
SELECT
    ID_log,
    fecha_gestion,
    nitsec
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.nitsec = t1.nitsec and t2.fecha_gestion < t1.fecha_gestion)
```